# Use Proportional Editing for whole faces not individual vertices

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, proportional-editing

I've made a tile grid where every face is disconnected from other faces ( no common vertices ). I would like to get a following effect:

[image]

But instead I get following:

[image]

How can use proportional editing for faces only, not vertices ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First you need to extrude all the faces individually.

[image]

Then select all the bottom vertices and hide them using <kbd>H</kbd> button to leave visible only the top faces and use proportional editing to move the faces up.

[image]

Then select all the faces, change **Pivot Point** to **Individual Origins** and scale on Z axis to zero using <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> buttons.

[image]

Then unhide hidden geometry with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> shortcut.

[image]